# Delete query error message "cant delete from specified tables"

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to run this delete query against a local Access tables, but I get error message

> can't delete from specified tables

Please provide me the proper SQL to copy and paste.

Thank you very much in advance, Nathaniel

```
DELETE RO.*, RO.STATUS, CO.ID, CO.PRINTED_DATE
FROM tmpReleasedOrders AS RO 
LEFT JOIN SYSADM_CUSTOMER_ORDER AS CO ON RO.orderID = CO.ID
WHERE (((RO.STATUS)="C" Or (RO.STATUS)="X")) OR (((CO.ID) Is Null)) OR (((CO.PRINTED_DATE) Is Null));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query depends on SYSADM_CUSTOMER_ORDER having a unique index on ID.

```
DELETE ro.*
FROM tmpReleasedOrders AS ro
LEFT JOIN SYSADM_CUSTOMER_ORDER AS CO 
ON RO.orderID = CO.ID
WHERE RO.STATUS="C" Or RO.STATUS="X" OR CO.ID Is Null OR CO.PRINTED_DATE Is Null
```

If you do not have an index on  SYSADM_CUSTOMER_ORDER, you can use something on these lines:

```
DELETE tmpreleasedorders.*
FROM tmpreleasedorders
WHERE  status IN ( "c", "x" )
OR orderid IN (
   SELECT orderid
   FROM   tmpreleasedorders AS ro
   LEFT JOIN sysadm_customer_order AS CO
   ON RO.orderid = CO.id
   WHERE  CO.id IS NULL
   OR CO.printed_date IS NULL)
```