# Access Delete Query Records from Table

Tags: ms-access

I have a query of that gives me the amount of claims above a limit for each part number/name for each month. I am looking to delete these above limit part from the data. I was trying to use a delete query to use the part number and date as the where conditions and the table of the raw data as the from condition. I will include a screen shot below.

[image]

It keeps telling me it can't delete the records from this table and I don't know why. I am also open to other solutions.

Comment: Your query is a cross-join, that's problem #1. Problem #2 is that you can't delete rows from a query unless the structure of the query points to unique rows in the underlying tables. It's impossible to tell if your query is doing that.

Comment: What, precisely, is the error message?

Comment: Could not delete from specified tables. I want all the records from the Claims above limit query to be deleted from the table of data where the part number and production date are the same.

Comment: Your query is not written correctly.  The where clauses are wrong.  Please type the following into the search bar *[ms-access] delete query*.   This is a very common question that has already been answered many times.  This question should be marked closed.  Also search *[ms-access] where clause*.

Comment: Does this provide any help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114273/delete-query-error-message-cant-delete-from-specified-tables

Comment: No really, I need this query to take all records that from "OLRemoved Asc" that match "qry_Claims Above Upper Limit ASC" by PartNo and ProductionYM to be deleted from "OLRemoved ASC". The datasheet view of the data looks correct but still gives me the same error no matter what I try to change.

Comment: The alternative could be that I use a select query and using a criteria that has a does not contain statement for exclude the records I don't want to see.